# Drop text files and process them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there any way that I can drop some text file, process them with PHP and get them back as an download without refresh the page? I have the code to drag and drop. I tried to use ajax but didn't find out how to download the ajax response.

Comment: You could use ajax to upload the file to PHP, then PHP could process the file, save it or whatever you want, and then it could send a message back to Javascript with a link to the file or with the contents of the file.

Comment: You can create a invisible iframe with the direct download link after.